# How do I get user input to allow another input after cycling through a loop?

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner, user-input

I'm fairly new to Java. I've done some C++ so I understand a lot of the concepts. I've been working on this code that allows me to ask for input on a tip calculator. I know some of the code is inconsistent but it's because I've been trying various methods to get it to display.

I can go through the program once asking for user input. However when I loop through it again, it just displays the same input I put in prior. I'm trying to get it to show then loop through, take new input and display that. I've been teaching myself this so it's a learning experience for me, however I'm stumped and not sure where to go from here. Any help is appreciated.

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TipApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        calculateTips();
    }

    public static void calculateTips () {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String pattern = "$##,###,###.00;"; // Pattern string for the decimal format
        DecimalFormat moneyFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern); // Decimal Money format
        NumberFormat defaultFormat = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
        defaultFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);
        String choice;
        double theBill;
        int theTip;
        int thePartySize;
        boolean isBillValid = true;
        boolean isTipValid = true;
        boolean isPartySizeValid = true;
        TipCalculator tipCalculator1 = new TipCalculator();
        System.out.println("*** Tip Calculator ***");

        do {
            System.out.print("\nEnter the bill amount: ");
            while (isBillValid) {
                try {
                    if (input.hasNextDouble()) {
                        theBill = input.nextDouble();
                        isBillValid = false;
                        tipCalculator1.setBillAmount(theBill);
                    }
                } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                    System.out.println(input.next() + " is not a valid number");
                }
                input.nextLine();
            }

            System.out.print("Enter your desired tip percentage (20 equals 20%): ");
            while (isTipValid) {
                if (input.hasNextInt()) {
                    theTip = input.nextInt();
                    isTipValid = false;
                    tipCalculator1.setTipPercentage(theTip);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Please enter a valid tip percentage.");
                    isTipValid = true;
                }
                input.nextLine();
            }

            System.out.print("Enter the size of your party: ");
            while (isPartySizeValid) {
                if (input.hasNextInt()) {
                    thePartySize = input.nextInt();
                    isPartySizeValid = false;
                    tipCalculator1.setPartyAmount(thePartySize);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Please enter a valid party size.");
                    isPartySizeValid = true;
                }
                input.nextLine();
            }

            System.out.println("*** Your Bill ***");
            System.out.print("\nBill Amount: ");
            System.out.println(moneyFormat.format(tipCalculator1.getBillAmount()));
            System.out.print("Tip Percentage: ");
            System.out.println(defaultFormat.format(tipCalculator1.getTipPercentage()));
            System.out.print("Party Size: ");
            System.out.println(tipCalculator1.getPartyAmount());
            System.out.print("\nTotal Bill (with Tip): ");
            System.out.print(moneyFormat.format(tipCalculator1.getTotalAmount()));
            System.out.print("\nShare for Each Individual: ");
            System.out.print(moneyFormat.format(tipCalculator1.getIndividualShare()));
            System.out.print("\nAnother Bill? (y/n): ");
            choice = scan.nextLine();

        } while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) ;
        System.out.println("\nGoodbye!");
    }
}

public class TipCalculator {
    private double billAmount;
    private int tipPercentage;
    private int partyAmount;


    // Constructor that holds 3 arguments
    public TipCalculator() {
        setBillAmount(billAmount);
        setTipPercentage(tipPercentage);
        setPartyAmount(partyAmount);
    }

    public double getBillAmount() {
        return billAmount;
    }

    public void setBillAmount(double billAmount) {
        this.billAmount = billAmount;
    }

    public double getTipPercentage() {
        return tipPercentage / 100f;
    }

    public void setTipPercentage(int tipPercentage) {
        this.tipPercentage = tipPercentage;
    }

    public int getPartyAmount() {
        return partyAmount;
    }

    public void setPartyAmount(int partyAmount) {
        this.partyAmount = partyAmount;
    }

    public double getIndividualShare() {
        return (getTotalAmount() / partyAmount);
    }

    public double getTotalAmount() {
        return (billAmount * getTipPercentage()) + billAmount;
    }
}

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tHIs.png
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, use only one Scanner object, you don't need more than that. Perhaps name is ***userInput***.

The problem you are having is because you are not resetting some key variables for the next bill to be calculated, in particular those that are used in conditions for your loops.

Take the following variables:

```
boolean isBillValid = true;
boolean isTipValid = true;
boolean isPartySizeValid = true;
double theBill;
int theTip;
int thePartySize;
```

and ***move*** them to the top of your **do** loop (the main outer loop) and initialize the String variable **choice** to hold a null string (""), for example:

```
do {
    choice = "";
    boolean isBillValid = false;
    boolean isTipValid = false;
    boolean isPartySizeValid = false;
    double theBill = 0.0d;
    int theTip = 0;
    int thePartySize = 0;
    System.out.print("\nEnter the bill amount: ");
    while (isBillValid) {
        try {
            //..... The rest of your code ....
```

This way the conditions for your loops will *not already be set* from the previous bill should the User enter 'y' to process another Bill.

In my opinion, every prompt which requires User input of some kind should ensure **valid** input and this would include the `Another Bill? (y/n):` prompt, for example:

```
while (choice.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.print("\nAnother Bill? (y/n): ");
    choice = userInput.nextLine();
    // Is only a 'y' or a 'n' supplied (regardless of letter case) 
    if (!choice.matches("(?i)[yn]")) {
        // No...inform User and have him her try again.
        System.out.println("Invalid input - 'y' or 'n' only! Try again...");
        choice = "";  // Reset the 'choice' variable to null string.
    }
}
```

The **if** statement condition in the above code utilizes the [String#matches()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm) method along with a small [Regular Expression](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html) (RegEx). Within the regex string, the `(?i)` means 'ignore letter case' and the `[yn]` means: matches **only** the 'y' or 'n' characters. So, if the supplied choice does **not** match either `y`, `Y`, `n`, or `N` then the condition is **true**.

This sort of validation should apply to all your prompts to the User so as to ensure a trouble free experience for the User, after all, typo's do happen. Take the Tip Percentage entry for example, what is to happen if the User enters `-10`?. This would be okay if your were applying a *discount coupon* or something but not so much for a tip. I think it might be best for the User to enter a value within a specific range like 0 to 100 (or whatever you like):

```
while (!isTipValid) {
    System.out.print("Enter your desired tip percentage (0 to 100): --> ");
    try {
        theTip = userInput.nextInt();
        // Is the tip percentage inclusively between 0 and 100?
        if (theTip < 0 || theTip > 100) {
             // No...
             throw new java.util.InputMismatchException();
        }
        isTipValid = true;
        tipCalculator1.setTipPercentage(theTip);
    } 
    catch (java.util.InputMismatchException ex) {
        System.out.println("Invalid tip percentage supplied (" + theTip + ")! Try again...");
    }
    userInput.nextLine();
}
```

In the above example loop code you will most likely notice a few things done differently here.

To begin with, the condition for the **while** loop better represents the name of the boolean variable `isTipValid`. The variable name is in a sense more like a question: **Is the Tip Valid?**. By default you have this variable initialized to **true** which is basically like saying `"Yes, the Tip is Valid!"` when in reality that hasn't been established yet. For better clarity I think this variable ***(and others like it)*** should be initialize to boolean **false** and then changed to boolean **true** only after it is *definitely* determined that the value supplied is indeed valid.

Another change you may have noticed is the fact that the displayed prompt string to the Console Window is placed within the **while** loop rather than above it. This ensures that if an invalid situation occurs and the prompt requires further input then the User will definitely know what is requested. It's a good idea that all of your prompt mechanism be contained within the **while** loop that pertains to it. The prompt string has also be modified to indicate to the User that a value within the range of 0 to 100 is expected.

Another change you may have noticed is the fact that the `if (input.hasNextInt()) {` line has been replaced with a **Try/Catch** mechanism. This actually provides a more definite means to ensure proper data entry since the [Scanner#hasNextInt()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_hasnextint.htm) method (and other hasNext...() methods) is better suited for tokenized input whereas a delimited series of integer numbers may be in or combined within that input. It can of course be used in this use-case but requires additional handling to accommodate all possible invalid situations.

You will also see an additional **if** statement that is used to check whether or not the value supplied is within the described range of 0 to 100. If it isn't then an **InputMismatchException** is thrown which forces the code-flow to immediately fall into the **catch** clause which ultimately indicates the problem to the User ans re-prompts for another value.

Doing the above similarly to your other Prompts will produce a much better outcome and you will know that the values supplied will be valid with the exception of the Bil Amount prompt:

```
while (!isBillValid) {
    System.out.print("Enter the bill amount: --> ");
    try {
        theBill = userInput.nextDouble();
        if (theBill < 0) {
            throw new java.util.InputMismatchException();
        }
        isBillValid = true;
        tipCalculator1.setBillAmount(theBill);
    } catch (java.util.InputMismatchException e) {
       System.out.println("Invalid Bill amount supplied (" + theBill + ")! Try again...");
    }
    userInput.nextLine();
}
```

This will work well for pretty much all invalid possibilities except for this simple typo: `3e4` example. This is considered a valid double value by the Scanner#nextDouble() method. The `e` or `E` within the supplied value is considered a value in Scientific E Notation and in its drawn out state is the same as a double value of **30000.0**. So, instead of the intended $34 bill the `3e4` ends up being a real healthy bill of $30,000.00. To cover this situation a slightly different approach will need to be used. In the code below you will see not just how the Bill Amount prompt code is done using this different approach but also all other prompts:

```
public void calculateTips() {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String pattern = "$##,###,###.00;"; // Pattern string for the decimal format
    java.text.DecimalFormat moneyFormat = new java.text.DecimalFormat(pattern); // Decimal Money format
    java.text.NumberFormat defaultFormat = java.text.NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
    defaultFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);
    String choice;

    TipCalculator tipCalculator1 = new TipCalculator();
    System.out.println("*** Tip Calculator ***");

    do {
        choice = "";
        boolean isBillValid = false;
        boolean isTipValid = false;
        boolean isPartySizeValid = false;
        double theBill = 0.0d;
        int theTip = 0;
        int thePartySize = 0;
        boolean breakAll = false;

        while (!isBillValid) {
            System.out.print("Enter the bill amount: --> ");
            String theBillStrg = userInput.nextLine().trim();
            // Is 'c' or 'C' for CANCEL entered?
            if (theBillStrg.equalsIgnoreCase("c")) {
                // Set breakAll to true break out of this loop.
                breakAll = true;
                break;
            }
            // If the value starts with a decimal point then  
            // prefix it with a 0.
            if (theBillStrg.startsWith(".")) {
                theBillStrg = "0" + theBillStrg;
            }
            // If the value ends with a decimal point then  
            // postfix it with a 0.
            else if (theBillStrg.endsWith(".")) {
                theBillStrg += "0";
            }
            // Is the supplied value a string representation of a 
            // Integer or double type value?
            if (theBillStrg.matches("\\d+(\\.\\d+)?")) {
                // Yes it is...
                // Parse the string value to a double type
                theBill = Double.parseDouble(theBillStrg);
                isBillValid = true;
                tipCalculator1.setBillAmount(theBill);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Invalid Bill amount supplied (" + theBillStrg + ")! Try again...");
            }
        }

        while (!isTipValid && !breakAll) {
            System.out.print("Enter your desired tip percentage (0 to 100): --> ");
            String theTipStrg = userInput.nextLine();
            // Is 'c' or 'C' for CANCEL entered?
            if (theTipStrg.equalsIgnoreCase("c")) {
                // Set breakAll to true break out of this loop.
                breakAll = true;
                break;
            }
            // Is a string representation of a Integer value supplied?
            if (theTipStrg.matches("\\d+")) {
                // Yes...Convert the string value to Integer
                theTip = Integer.parseInt(theTipStrg);
                // Is the tip percentage inclusively between 0 and 100?
                if (theTip < 0 || theTip > 100) {
                    // No...
                    System.out.println("Out of Range tip percentage supplied (" + theTip + ")! Try again...");
                    continue;
                }
                isTipValid = true;
                tipCalculator1.setTipPercentage(theTip);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Invalid tip percentage supplied (" + theTipStrg + ")! Try again...");
            }
        }

        while (!isPartySizeValid && !breakAll) {
            System.out.print("Enter the size of your party: ");
            String partySizeStrg = userInput.nextLine();
            // Is 'c' or 'C' for CANCEL entered?
            if (partySizeStrg.equalsIgnoreCase("c")) {
                // Set breakAll to true break out of this loop.
                breakAll = true;
                break;
            }
            else if (partySizeStrg.matches("\\d+")) {
                thePartySize = Integer.parseInt(partySizeStrg);
                isPartySizeValid = true;
                tipCalculator1.setPartyAmount(thePartySize);
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Invalid party size supplied (" + partySizeStrg + ")! Try again...");
            }
        }

        if (!breakAll) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("======================================");
            System.out.println("*** Your Bill ***");
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("Bill Amount: ");
            System.out.println(moneyFormat.format(tipCalculator1.getBillAmount()));
            System.out.print("Tip Percentage: ");
            System.out.println(defaultFormat.format(tipCalculator1.getTipPercentage()));
            System.out.print("Party Size: ");
            System.out.println(tipCalculator1.getPartyAmount());
            System.out.print("\nTotal Bill (with Tip): ");
            System.out.println(moneyFormat.format(tipCalculator1.getTotalAmount()));
            System.out.print("\nShare for Each Individual: ");
            System.out.println(moneyFormat.format(tipCalculator1.getIndividualShare()));
            System.out.println("======================================");
        }
        
        while (choice.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.print("\nAnother Bill? (y/n): ");
            choice = userInput.nextLine();
            if (!choice.matches("(?i)[yn]")) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input - 'y' or 'n' only! Try again...");
                choice = "";
            }
        }
        System.out.println();

    } while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y"));
    System.out.println("\nGoodbye!");
}
```